# DNN: dnnConfirm needs two clicks to show

Tags: javascript, jquery, dotnetnuke

I'm using the below code to show a `dnnConfirm` confirmation popup before proceeding. The issue is that it requires two clicks to show. And when I close it and click the button again it needs 3 clicks and so on and so forth.

I'm new to DNN any idea what must be wrong here. Please guide

**This is my hyperlink button:**

```
<a id="link-btn" class="dnnSecondaryAction" onclick="setInfo();"/>Save Info</a>
```

**This is my confirmation code:**

```
$("#link-btn").dnnConfirm({
            text: "<div class='MS'>Save info?</div>",
            title: "Confirm Save",
            yesText: 'Yes',
            noText: 'No',
            isButton: true
});
//handle user decision
$("#link-btn").click(function (e, isYES) {
        if (isYES) {
            saveUserInfo(userID);
        }
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Is you click code being executed?

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here that could be causing problems for you.

Unfortunately, you didn't include code for the setInfo() method but I'd look there first.  E.g. Is this method returning false?

Another issue could be returning false from

```
$("#link-btn").click(function (e, isYES) {
```

which could be short circuiting some other desired behavior.  In general, you're better off using:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

instead.

I would also note that $("#link-btn").click() probably doesn't do what you think it does.  Rather than handle the results of the confirm dialog, this is fired when the confirm dialog *is launched*.  (e.g. #link-btn is *clicked*)

To address the potential causes for your two-click-show problem (and to also be able to handle the results of your confirm dialog) I'd recommend rewriting as follows:

**Hyperlink**

```
<a id="link-btn" class="dnnSecondaryAction"/>Save Info</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#link-btn").dnnConfirm({
            text: "<div class='MS'>Save info?</div>",
            title: "Confirm Save",
            yesText: 'Yes',
            noText: 'No',
            isButton: true,
            callbackTrue: function() {
                saveUserInfo(userID);  // assuming userID is a global
            }
});

$("#link-btn").click(function (e) {
    setInfo();
    // in this case, you don't need to call e.preventDefault() 
    // as dnnConfirm will handle that for you
});
```